# Using Object Mapper throw an Exception when whitespace key is passed in the map

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I am invoking a REST **POST** API with following body:

```
{
"ref":{" ":"123"}
}
```

In the backend I am using **Object Mapper** to deserialize the above body to a POJO object as shown below -

```
public class POJO{

    public Map<String,String> ref;

    public Map<String,String> getRef(){
        return ref;
    }

    public void setRef(Map<String,String> map){
        this.ref = map;
    }
}
```

But I want to throw an exception when whitespace key is sent as in the above case. Currently Object mapper allows the above behavior.

I don't want to use a custom deserializer.

Is there a way using **jackson annotation** or using some available module which can be registered in Object mapper so that it doesn't allows the above body and throws an exception?

Comment: @jaco0646 updated the question.

Comment: `if (string.trim().isEmpty()) throws ***` is this what you want?

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado I can do that but is there a way to configure object mapper so that it throws the exception itself or using jackson annotations?

Comment: One obvious solution is to convert the `Map<String,String>` into its own POJO.

Comment: @jaco0646 thanks for the suggestion but I can’t use this due to design constraints.